# is there a XML parser library for micropython?

Tags: xml-parsing, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Is there an XML parser library for micropython? I would like to parse an XML file in a text file or string. This is for a Pico and I am using Thonny. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[xmltok](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/tree/3a6ab0b46d6471bee00ae815444c624709dd4cdd/micropython/xmltok) is a very simple XML token parser for MicroPython that gives rather crude `START_TAG` / `END_TAG`-style event processing. It has a couple of limitations:

- it can only read from a file, not from a string returned from (say) a request;
- it seems to enjoy returning a `RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration` more often than I would like.

It is, however, part of the standard [micropython-lib](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib) library, so it is nominally blessed by the MicroPython developers.

Building on top of xmltok is [ThunderEX / uxml2dict](https://github.com/ThunderEX/uxml2dict). It can't read from a string either, but does return a more useful data structure.